# how to make doughnut chart portions, buttons

Tags: javascript, button, chart.js

I have a doughnut chart made by Chart.js. When my mouse comes over a portion, the portion label appears such as RED: 300.

What I want is to show this label in the middle when I click it.

I have the code to write in the middle, but I need to know how to make portions to behave as buttons.

Comment: I guess you can use 
// Function - Determines whether to execute the customTooltips function instead of drawing the built in tooltips (See [Advanced - External Tooltips](#advanced-usage-custom-tooltips))
    customTooltips: false,
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: not yet, but I think I will

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `getSegmentsAtEvent(evt)` method.

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = myDoughnutChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
    // => activePoints is an array of segments on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
};
```

If `activePoints` is empty, that means you can just `return` because no segment was clicked. Otherwise, go ahead and draw your tooltip.